# Ruby hash - how to use hash value when populating object?

Tags: ruby, hash, ruby-1.9

For a pack of playing cards:

How can I use the suit hash (below) when creating a pack?

I have:

```
class PackOfCards

  SUITS={H: 'Hearts', S:'Spades', D:'Diamonds', C:'Clubs'}
  CARDS=['A','2','3','4','5','6','7','8','9','10','J','Q','K']


  attr_accessor :pack_name, :cards

  def initialize(pack_name)

    @pack_name= pack_name
    @cards = []
    (0..3).each do |suit|
      (0..12).each do |number|
        @cards << PlayingCard.new(self, (SUITS[suit].value), CARDS[number])
      end 
    end 
  end 
end

class PlayingCard

  attr_accessor :pack, :card_number, :card_suit


  def initialize(pack, suit, number)
    @card_suit = suit
    @card_number = number
  end 

end
```

but I get:

```
pack_of_cards.rb:16:in `block (2 levels) in initialize': 
undefined method `value' for 
{:H=>"Hearts", :S=>"Spades", :D=>"Diamonds", :C=>"Clubs"}:Hash (NoMethodError)
```

Comment: `SUITS` is invalid Ruby expression.

Comment: Updated to use hash's `{}` syntax (not `[]`) but same error :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a corrected version, check the comments :

```
class PackOfCards
  SUITS={H: 'Hearts', S:'Spades', D:'Diamonds', C:'Clubs'} # Use curly braces to define a hash, [] braces will define an array containing one hash
  CARDS=['A','2','3','4','5','6','7','8','9','10','J','Q','K']
  attr_accessor :pack_name, :cards

  def initialize(pack_name)
    @pack_name= pack_name
    @cards = []
    SUITS.each_key do |suit| # each_key is better since it gives you the key of the hash
      (0..12).each do |number|
        puts PackOfCards::SUITS[suit]
        @cards << PlayingCard.new(self, (PackOfCards::SUITS[suit]), PackOfCards::CARDS[number]) # Call the hash with the right key to get the Suit
      end
    end
  end
end

class PlayingCard 
  attr_accessor :pack, :card_number, :card_suit

  def initialize(pack, suit, number)
    @card_suit = suit
    @card_number = number
  end

end
```

Comment: Yes, I like it.  I changed the `PackOfCards::SUITS[suit]` expression to `SUITS[suit]` as it is within the class.  I welcome thoughts on that change :)

Comment: btw (others) I am using a hash rather than an array (which I used initially) because ultimately I want be to able to use either the one letter suit name or the full description.  Right now I could also just use an array and grab the capitalized first letter, but this is homework (that I set myself) and wanted to see how to use a hash in this context.

Answer (score 2):

<strike>Your `SUITS` is invalid expression.</strike> Perhaps you wanted to do this:

```
SUITS = %w[Hearts Spades Diamonds Clubs]
```

And it is not clear what you are doing, but perhaps you should be doing this:

```
@cards =
SUITS.flat_map{|suit| CARDS.map{|number| PlayingCard.new(self, suit, number)}}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your `Suit` definition and lookup don't look valid.

How about something like this (assuming the output is a pack of cards with all suit and numbers) -

```
class PackOfCards

  SUITS = ['Hearts', 'Spades', 'Diamonds', 'Clubs']
  CARDS=['A','2','3','4','5','6','7','8','9','10','J','Q','K']


  attr_accessor :pack_name, :cards

  def initialize(pack_name)

    @pack_name= pack_name
    @cards = []
    (0..3).each do |suit|
      (0..12).each do |number|
        @cards << PlayingCard.new(self, (SUITS[suit]), CARDS[number])
      end 
    end 
  end 
end

class PlayingCard

  attr_accessor :pack, :card_number, :card_suit


  def initialize(pack, suit, number)
    @card_suit = suit
    @card_number = number
  end 

end
```

Answer (score 0):

You've actually put a hash in an array. To access the key, value pairs you'd have to access the array element first like this:

```
SUITS.first[:H]
```